# How to retrieve unpaid amount of each invoice for finance charges?

Tags: sql, postgresql, invoice

I am working on implementing finance charges, but don't know how to retrieve the unpaid amount of each invoice. I am not new to SQL, however this problem has me stumped. Forgive me if I just didn't search properly.

So, let us say I have an invoice table:

```
 id | amount   
----+--------------
 1  | 50.00         
 2  | 50.00      
 3  | 50.00     
 4  | 50.00    
 5  | 50.00
```

And a payments table:

```
amount   
--------------
50.00       
25.00
```

The result set should be this:

```
 invoice_id | unpaid_amount   
------------+--------------       
 2          | 25.00      
 3          | 50.00     
 4          | 50.00     
 5          | 50.00
```

Of course, there is quite a bit more to add to implement finance charges, but I think I can get the rest.

**Edit:** Sorry, an oversight of mine. The id's are not related. Removed payment id column.

**Edit 2:** These are fictual numbers, the real life numbers will be anything, so no matches can be made on the amounts.

**Edit 3:** And here I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/139fa4/3) to show what I have so far, based on @GordonLinoff second answer. I would appreciate a cleaner approach than the kludgy SQL I concocted.

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables?  Are the `id`s related?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no the id's are not related.

Comment: If there is no defined relationship between the tables is there anything else usable to determine the order of processing, like maybe a date?

Comment: @Belayer Yes, for the order of processing, there is a date (primary sort) and the id (secondary sort) . I have a partial solution based off of GordonLinoff second answer, but it looks horrendous. I would much appreciate a clean good SQL.

Comment: That is a really bad data model. Your payments table is missing a foreign key to the invoices table. What  if you issue two invoices on the same day? Then you are not able to properly link a payment to an invoice.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, so how would you go about to match uneven payments to invoices? In real life, payment amounts and invoice amounts do not match. One payment may apply to zero invoices OR several invoices.

Comment: @theGtknerd: exactly and that's why you need a foreign key from the payment table to the invoice table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `join`:

```
select i.id as invoice_id,
       (i.amount - coalesce(p.amount, 0)) as net_amount
from invoice i left join
     payment p
     on i.id = p.id;
```

EDIT:

Or, you may want:

```
select i.*,
       (case when sum(i.amount) over (order by i.id) < p.amount 
             then i.amount
             else greatest(p.amount - sum(i.amount) over (order by i.id) + i.amount, 0)
        end) as amount_paid
from invoice i cross join
     (select sum(amount) as amount
      from payment
     ) p;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/139fa4/17) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. Could you check my [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/139fa4/3) for posible improvements? It seems really crude.

Comment: @theGtknerd . . . The fiddle really helps.  I fixed the logic and you can see the results in the fiddle.  Note that this is for `amount_paid` rather than `amount_unpaid`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using `LEFT JOIN` and subtract amounts from both table. `COALSECE` is here to prevent you from getting `NULL` when there is no payment.

```
select
     i.id as invoice_id
    ,i.amount - coalesce(p.amount,0) as amount
from invoice i 
left join payments p
    on p.id = i.id
```

If in your `payments` talbe can be more than one payment for an invoice you should group `payments` before joining it to `invoice`.

```
select
     i.id as invoice_id
    ,i.amount - coalesce(p.amount,0) as amount
from invoice i 
left join (select id, sum(amount) as amount  from payments group by id) p
    on p.id = i.id
```